# how to store recyclerview data on onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onsaveinstancestate

I want to save data from the API in the RecyclerView so that when rotating the screen is not reloaded

I think I can use onSaveInstanceState but still don't really understand how to use it

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final RecyclerView rvTVShow = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_shows);
    rvTVShow.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvTVShow.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MovieResponse> call = apiService.getTVShow(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MovieResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            final List<Movies> movies = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getResults();

           TvShowAdapter tvShowAdapter = new TvShowAdapter(movies , R.layout.list_movies);
           rvTVShow.setAdapter(tvShowAdapter);

           ....
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966608/save-list-of-objects-in-onsaveinstancestate

Comment: @AnasMehar Good point, but not exactly what he wants. He wants an explanation so he can understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will explain how savedInstanceState works while refactoring your code.

First: Create a global Movie object and an Adapter for it

```
  List<Movies> movies = new ArrayList();
  TvShowAdapter tvShowAdapter = null;
```

Re-initialize adapter under activity onCreate

```
  tvShowAdapter = new TvShowAdapter(movies , R.layout.list_movies);
       rvTVShow.setAdapter(tvShowAdapter);
```

Create a new method to handle movie
data population

```
 public void populateRV(List<Movies> movies)
{
      this.movies = movies;
   //notify adapter about the new record
      tvShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
 }
```

Insert data to Movies object under your Response callback

```
  movies = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getResults();
 populateRV(movies);
```

Everytime the orientation of an activity changes Android resets the states of all views by redrawing them. This causes non persistent data to be lost. But before redrawing views it calls the method  **onSavedInstanceState**

Hence we can prevent state loss by saving the state of our views using the already defined onSavedInstanceState method provided by android.

Add the following block inside the overridden onSavedInstanceState method of your activity

```
 //this saves the data to a temporary storage
 savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("movie_data", movies);
 //call super to commit your changes
 super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
```

Next is to recover the data after orientation change is completed

Add the following block in your activity onCreate and make sure it comes after initializing your adapter

```
 //...add the recyclerview adapter initialization block here before checking for saved data

 //Check for saved data
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
 // Retrieve the data you saved
 movies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("movie_data");

  //Call method to reload adapter record
 populateRV(movies);
 } else {
 //No data to retrieve
//Load your API values here.
 }
```

Comment: great explanation. wish I knew you wanted that much explanation :) Congratulations to @GiddyNaya